# Ubuntu 20.04 there is no ksnip in the list of possible applications

Tags: 20.04, screenshot, ksnapshot

I want to open an image in ksnip that is installed as snap package but there is no such program in the list of possible options. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to open this file from within ksnip `File > Open`?

Comment: Perhaps the `Exec=` line in the installed desktop file does not add a placeholder for a file argument. Then, the launcher will not be included in the "Open With" list.